# Virtual async methods in metro c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, async-await

I want to define a virtual method that is not async in the base class but it is async in the derived class and the caller call it using a delegate (Actually it is an ICommand activated by a button on screen) how can I do this.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    BIONESSBindingCommand mLogoffCommand;

    public ICommand LogoffCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mLogoffCommand == null)
            {
                mLogoffCommand = new BIONESSBindingCommand(
                    Param => Logoff(), //Command DoWork
                    Param => true); //Always can execute
            }

            return mLogoffCommand;
        }
    }

    public virtual Task Logoff()
    {
        DoLogoff();
        return null; //???
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override async Task Logoff()
    {
        await SomeWoAsyncWork();
        base.Logoff(); //Has warninngs
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't what you're doing just work (except for specifying properties and methods inside of a constructor)?

Answer (score 6):

Call `Task.FromResult` to get a completed `Task`. Also, `await` it in the derived class (this will enable error propagation).

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public virtual Task Logoff()
  {
    DoLogoff();
    return Task.FromResult(false);
  }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public override async Task Logoff()
  {
    await SomeWoAsyncWork();
    await base.Logoff();
  }
}
```

Comment: No. `Task<bool>` derives from `Task`.

Comment: Right, that works syntactically, but it's a bit like a method that returns Object.

Comment: Not at all. It's a method that returns a base type. With `Task`, no semantics are lost and there are no boxing issues. I agree that it would be cleaner to have a `Task.FromResult()` that returned just a plain `Task` (and I do provide one in my [AsyncEx Library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/)), but there isn't one provided by .NET. They decided that returning `Task<T>` is sufficient for this scenario.

Comment: For anyone using the Microsoft Async package with .NET 4, a lot of these static methods are in TaskEx, not Task, including TaskEx.FromResult(...)

Comment: Can we use this  await Task.FromResult in order to get rid off warnings on virtual methods if my override method is async-await? is it safe?

Comment: @batmaci: Yes; just be aware that it's a synchronous implementation of an asynchronous interface method.